# Add previous row value to current row and so on Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Hi the following is my DataSet

```
           MD  Incl.    Azi.
0        0.00   0.00  350.00
1      161.00   0.00  350.00
2      261.00   0.00  350.00
3      361.00   0.00  350.00
4      461.00   0.00  350.00
```

I would like to perform a calculation, create a new column and in this column add the row value to the previous row value in the column and so on.

```
import pandas as pd
import math
import numpy as np

#open excel file
df = pd.read_excel
print(df)

for i in range (1, len(df)):
    incl = np.deg2rad(df['Incl.'])
    df['TVD_diff'] = (((df['MD'] - df['MD'].shift())/2)*(np.cos(incl).shift() + np.cos(incl)))

print(df)

           MD  Incl.    Azi.         TVD
0        0.00   0.00  350.00         NaN
1      161.00   0.00  350.00  161.000000
2      261.00   0.00  350.00  100.000000
3      361.00   0.00  350.00  100.000000
4      461.00   0.00  350.00  100.000000
```

I would like the TVD column to be

```
TVD
NaN
161
261
361
461
```

and so on by adding its current value to the value before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cumsum`

```
df['tvd'] = df['tvd'].cumsum()
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

txt = """           MD  Incl.    Azi.
0        0.00   0.00  350.00
1      161.00   0.00  350.00
2      261.00   0.00  350.00
3      361.00   0.00  350.00
4      461.00   0.00  350.00"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), sep='\s\s+')

for i in range (1, len(df)):
    incl = np.deg2rad(df['Incl.'])
    df['TVD_diff'] = (((df['MD'] - df['MD'].shift())/2)*(np.cos(incl).shift() + np.cos(incl)))

df['TVD_diff'] = df['TVD_diff'].cumsum()

print(df)
```

Output:

```
      MD  Incl.   Azi.  TVD_diff
0    0.0    0.0  350.0       NaN
1  161.0    0.0  350.0     161.0
2  261.0    0.0  350.0     261.0
3  361.0    0.0  350.0     361.0
4  461.0    0.0  350.0     461.0
```